# how to implement Dijkstra algorithm in mapbox or leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, dijkstra, path-finding

I wanted to make a school campus map with custom roads and apply the path finding algorithm
I tried mapbox but I couldn't find in docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through the Leaflet routing machine. It is  a open source platform for routing.
https://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/